# Installing php_ffmpeg in xaamp with php 5.6 above

Tags: php, ffmpeg

How do I install the ffmpeg on xaamp with php version 5.6?

It is installed on the local machine and converting videos format through CMD, but not coordination with the local server.

Comment: https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Answer (score 0):

You can follow steps from here or do the following steps.

1. Download ffmpeg from here: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html
2. Copy php_ffmpeg.dll from the php5 folder to the
   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.9-2\ext
3. Copy files from common to the windows/system32 folder
4. Add extension=php_ffmpeg.dll to php.ini file ( \apache...php.ini )
5. Restarted all services (Apache, PHP...)
6. And enable "extension=php_ffmpeg.dll" directive in your php.ini.